# Error with JSON + Jquery Ajax + PHP + MYSQL

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, json

I have the followin PHP file (a function of it):

```
public function get_hotels(){
   $hoteles = new HotelModel();
   $query = "SELECT * FROM hotel";
   $hoteles = $hoteles->execute_query($query);
   echo json_encode($hoteles);
}
```

And this is my jQuery script:

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "index.php?controller=ExcursionTypes&action=get_hotels",
   dataType:"json",
   success: function(response){
    alert(typeof (response[0].hotel_name));
    //$("#pickups_fields").html(response[0].hotel_name);
   },
   error:function(response){
    alert("ERROR");
   }
});
```

Firebug throws me this JSON:

```
[{"id_hotel":"1","hotel_name":"Apt.Playa del Ingles", "hotel_phone":"928762629",
"hotel_corporation_id":"1","hotel_state_id":"1"},
{"id_hotel":"2","hotel_name":"LZ",
"hotel_phone":"928762629","hotel_corporation_id":"1", 
"hotel_state_id":"2"}]
```

I want to read both hotel_name fields and I can't.

I'm sure you're giving me the solution or a link to solve it.

Although I'm looking for it too.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript is case sensitive, so you should write `dataType`, not `datatype`.

JSON that you get as a response is correct and `response[0].hotel_name` would work, but because you mistyped `dataType`, the response is not parsed as a JSON and therefore you can't access it the way you did.

Comment: I've change the datatype into dataType and it's still throwing me the string "ERROR" in the "error:" property

Answer (score 0):

Try iterating over the objects in response, like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "index.php?controller=ExcursionTypes&action=get_hotels",
    dataType:"json",
    success: function(response){
        $.each(response, function(i, hotel) {
            alert(typeof (hotel.hotel_name));
            //$("#pickups_fields").html(hotel.hotel_name);
        });
    },
    error:function(response){
        alert("ERROR");
    }
});
```

Comment: Didn't notice the dataType issue, so amended that. I still think this is the approach OP should take though.

Comment: I've change the datatype into dataType and it's still throwing me the string "ERROR" in the "error:" property

Comment: Try using [`$.getJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) instead and see if that works.

Comment: it seems that the dataType:"json", line contains an error because when I comment it it shows me what I code in the success statement

Comment: that would mean that the response couldn't be parsed as JSON, which is strange, because the JSON you've posted is correct.

Comment: @Chris P - he cannot use `$.getJSON()`, as this is a POST request.

Comment: Really, OP should be using a GET request if he is expecting a response from the server.

Comment: so if JSON format is correct why isnt parsed my data with dataType? how can I parse it because $.parseJSON() doesn't work....

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "index.php?controller=ExcursionTypes&action=get_hotels",
    dataType:"json",
    success: function(response){
        for(key in response) {
            alert(typeof (response.hotel_name[key]));
        });
    },
    error:function(response){
        alert("ERROR");
    }
});
```